# I'm having an issue parsing an XML string with Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm having trouble parsing an xml table using python. I'm new to parsing these types of files. I'm currently using the ElementTree library. Id like to grab specific attributes for each row of the "UsedPartTab" table using a for loop. More specifically I'd like to assign the following attributes to a variable...PartNo, UsedQty, InvoiceNo. What would be the best way for me to go about doing this?

I've tried indexing the specific tag within the root document with no success. I've also tried the findall, find, and get methods.

```
    def GetPartsUsedList():
        request = GET_TICKET_INFO
        response = requests.post(url=GSPN_URL, verify=False, proxies=proxies, headers={"content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "SOAPAction": '"www.samsungasc.com/GetTicketInfo"'}, data=request)
        xml = ET.fromstring(response.text)
        root = xml[0][0][0]
        print(root.text)

GetPartsUsedList()

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rootdoc>
    <RetCode>0</RetCode>
    <ErrMsg></ErrMsg>
    <Carrier></Carrier>
    <CarrierName></CarrierName>
    <TicketNo>4149142579</TicketNo>
    <SCode1>01</SCode1>
    <SCode2></SCode2>
    <SCode3></SCode3>
    <SCode4>XC</SCode4>
    <IrisDefectCode>ARCS</IrisDefectCode>
    <IrisRepairCode>DPRT</IrisRepairCode>
    <AlertMessage></AlertMessage>
    <HighRisk></HighRisk>
    <Table>
        <Name>UsedPartTab</Name>
        <Column>
            <Name>SeqNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>PartStatus</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>PartNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>Description</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>Location</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>UsedQty</Name>
            <Type>Decimal</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>RequestNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>PONo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>SONo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>InvoiceNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>InvoiceItemNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>DefectSerialNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>POStatus</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>TrackingNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>TrackingHyperLink</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>PostGoodsIssue</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <ROW>
            <SeqNo>0001</SeqNo>
            <PartStatus>Used</PartStatus>
            <PartNo>0M75P-21-ESGN</PartNo>
            <Description></Description>
            <Location></Location>
            <UsedQty>1</UsedQty>
            <RequestNo></RequestNo>
            <PONo></PONo>
            <SONo></SONo>
            <InvoiceNo></InvoiceNo>
            <InvoiceItemNo>0</InvoiceItemNo>
            <DefectSerialNo></DefectSerialNo>
            <POStatus></POStatus>
            <TrackingNo></TrackingNo>
            <TrackingHyperLink></TrackingHyperLink>
            <PostGoodsIssue>N</PostGoodsIssue>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <SeqNo>0002</SeqNo>
            <PartStatus>Used</PartStatus>
            <PartNo>DE26-00126B</PartNo>
            <Description>TRANS H.V;SHV-U1870D,120V,2545,2385V/3.4</Description>
            <Location></Location>
            <UsedQty>1</UsedQty>
            <RequestNo></RequestNo>
            <PONo></PONo>
            <SONo></SONo>
            <InvoiceNo>8424097053</InvoiceNo>
            <InvoiceItemNo>0</InvoiceItemNo>
            <DefectSerialNo></DefectSerialNo>
            <POStatus></POStatus>
            <TrackingNo></TrackingNo>
            <TrackingHyperLink></TrackingHyperLink>
            <PostGoodsIssue>P</PostGoodsIssue>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <SeqNo>0003</SeqNo>
            <PartStatus>Used</PartStatus>
            <PartNo>DE60-20066A</PartNo>
            <Description>BOLT-FLAT;MSWR,L100,UNF1/4</Description>
            <Location></Location>
            <UsedQty>1</UsedQty>
            <RequestNo></RequestNo>
            <PONo></PONo>
            <SONo></SONo>
            <InvoiceNo>8456512557</InvoiceNo>
            <InvoiceItemNo>0</InvoiceItemNo>
            <DefectSerialNo></DefectSerialNo>
            <POStatus></POStatus>
            <TrackingNo></TrackingNo>
            <TrackingHyperLink></TrackingHyperLink>
            <PostGoodsIssue>P</PostGoodsIssue>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <SeqNo>0004</SeqNo>
            <PartStatus>Used</PartStatus>
            <PartNo>DE94-03275A</PartNo>
            <Description>ASSY PANEL OUTER;MD4,BLACK,P/OUTER+ASSY-</Description>
            <Location></Location>
            <UsedQty>1</UsedQty>
            <RequestNo></RequestNo>
            <PONo></PONo>
            <SONo></SONo>
            <InvoiceNo>8456512595</InvoiceNo>
            <InvoiceItemNo>0</InvoiceItemNo>
            <DefectSerialNo></DefectSerialNo>
            <POStatus></POStatus>
            <TrackingNo></TrackingNo>
            <TrackingHyperLink></TrackingHyperLink>
            <PostGoodsIssue>P</PostGoodsIssue>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <SeqNo>0005</SeqNo>
            <PartStatus>Used</PartStatus>
            <PartNo>DE96-00269A</PartNo>
            <Description>ASSY HVC;SMH7175,-,-,0.91UF HVC,-,-</Description>
            <Location></Location>
            <UsedQty>1</UsedQty>
            <RequestNo></RequestNo>
            <PONo></PONo>
            <SONo></SONo>
            <InvoiceNo>8456090576</InvoiceNo>
            <InvoiceItemNo>0</InvoiceItemNo>
            <DefectSerialNo></DefectSerialNo>
            <POStatus></POStatus>
            <TrackingNo></TrackingNo>
            <TrackingHyperLink></TrackingHyperLink>
            <PostGoodsIssue>P</PostGoodsIssue>
        </ROW>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Name>RecommendedPartTab</Name>
        <Column>
            <Name>PartNo</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>Description</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Name>Comments</Name>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Column>
    </Table>
```

Comment: You say you’ve tried `findall`, `find`, and `get` methods.  Could you show us what you’ve tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('./sample2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for table in root.findall('Table'):
    if table.find('Name').text == 'UsedPartTab':
        for child in table.findall('Column'):
            print (child.find('Name').text)
```

Comment: I'm reading this in as a string so I used the below function. It returns nothing. Did I interpret this incorrectly? def GetPartsUsedList():
    request = GET_TICKET_INFO
    response = requests.post(url=GSPN_URL, verify=False, proxies=proxies, headers={"content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "SOAPAction": '"www.samsungasc.com/GetTicketInfo"'}, data=request)
    tree = ET.fromstring(response.text)
    for table in tree.findall('Table'):
        if table.find('Name').text == 'UsedPartTab':
            for child in table.findall('Column'):
                print(child.find('Name').text)

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<rootdoc>

    <Table>
        <ROW>
            <SeqNo>0001</SeqNo>
            <PartStatus>Used</PartStatus>
            <PartNo>0M75P-21-ESGN</PartNo>
            <Description></Description>
            <Location></Location>
            <UsedQty>1</UsedQty>
            <RequestNo></RequestNo>
            <PONo></PONo>
            <SONo></SONo>
            <InvoiceNo></InvoiceNo>
            <InvoiceItemNo>0</InvoiceItemNo>
            <DefectSerialNo></DefectSerialNo>
            <POStatus></POStatus>
            <TrackingNo></TrackingNo>
            <TrackingHyperLink></TrackingHyperLink>
            <PostGoodsIssue>N</PostGoodsIssue>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <SeqNo>0002</SeqNo>
            <PartStatus>Used</PartStatus>
            <PartNo>DE26-00126B</PartNo>
            <Description>TRANS H.V;SHV-U1870D,120V,2545,2385V/3.4</Description>
            <Location></Location>
            <UsedQty>1</UsedQty>
            <RequestNo></RequestNo>
            <PONo></PONo>
            <SONo></SONo>
            <InvoiceNo>8424097053</InvoiceNo>
            <InvoiceItemNo>0</InvoiceItemNo>
            <DefectSerialNo></DefectSerialNo>
            <POStatus></POStatus>
            <TrackingNo></TrackingNo>
            <TrackingHyperLink></TrackingHyperLink>
            <PostGoodsIssue>P</PostGoodsIssue>
        </ROW></Table></rootdoc>
  '''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
fields = ['PartNo', 'UsedQty', 'InvoiceNo']
rows = root.findall('.//Table/ROW')
for row in rows:
    for field in fields:
        val = row.find('./{}'.format(field)).text
        print('{} : {}'.format(field,val))
```

output

```
PartNo : 0M75P-21-ESGN
UsedQty : 1
InvoiceNo : None
PartNo : DE26-00126B
UsedQty : 1
InvoiceNo : 8424097053
```